# What is the reduced mass of a diamond unit cell?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, phonons

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.07927) paper to study so-called collapse models. However, the paper isn't really relevant to understand the problem here.

In the paper, the authors are considering a bulk vibration (optical phonon) in a diamond and want to quantify the zero-point fluctuations $x_{ZPF} = \frac{\hbar}{\omega m^*}$ of one phonon mode, with $\omega$ the frequency of the mode.

They then make the following claim with regards to the oscillator mass $m^*$

> $m^*$ is the reduced mass of the (diamond) unit cell: $m^* = 6 u$

with $u$ the atomic mass unit. I really don't understand where this number comes from and I think it's wrong. First of all, diamond has 8 atoms per unit cell (FCC). The mass of one carbon atom is given by $12 u \neq 6u$.

One possible explanation is that they consider optical phonons, so 4 of the 8 atoms per unit cell vibrate in one direction and the remaining 4 oscillate in the other direction. Then, one could argue that $m_{eff} \approx 12 u / 2 = 6 u$.

I am not convinced by this reasoning, though.

Comment: Actually, a diamond cubic cell has 2 atoms per primitive unit cell. A fcc primitive unit cell has 1 atom in it.

Comment: @JonCuster [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_cubic) link says otherwise.

Comment: And Wikipedia is not a physics or materials science textbook. Google ‘diamond cubic primitive unit cell’ and learn the difference between a ‘conventional’ and ‘primitive’ cell. For bonus points understand how a Wigner-Seitz cell is constructed.